# TransformedDistribution will not accept a parameter

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Why does

```
TransformedDistribution[x^2, x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]]
```

give the proper answer ($\text{BetaDistribution}\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]$)

while

```
Assuming[a \[Element] Reals \[And] a > 0,
 TransformedDistribution[a x^2, 
  x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]]]
```

not?

Comment: David, is there any reason why you often make new tags instead of trying to use existing ones?

Comment: I just typed what I thought were appropriate tags, and the site accepted them.  I certainly think there should be a tag devoted to a function call, `TransformedDistribution`, don't you?

Comment: Note that even replacing $a$ with an actual positive real number does not lead to an explicit output.

Comment: Anyway: in general, `TransformedDistribution[]` will try to simplify whenever possible; in this case, it doesn't know what to do. You can still use it in functions like `PDF[]`: `PDF[TransformedDistribution[a x^2, x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], Assumptions -> a > 0], x]`

Comment: @MarcoB:  Curious:  TransformedDistribution works if I let $a=1$ but not otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TransformedDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html) accepts a parameter; although, in the case given, it does not know a common distribution that corresponds to the resulting distribution. Nonetheless, the usual probability functions work with the result.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

dist[a_] := TransformedDistribution[a*x^2,
  x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}],
  Assumptions -> a > 0]

DistributionParameterAssumptions[dist[a]]

(* a > 0 *)

#[dist[a]] & /@ {Mean, Variance, Moment[#, n] &}

(* {a/3, (4 a^2)/45, a^n/(1 + 2 n)} *)

\[DoubleStruckA] = 2;

SeedRandom[1234];
data = RandomVariate[dist[\[DoubleStruckA]], 1000];

Show[
 Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"],
 Plot[Evaluate@PDF[dist[\[DoubleStruckA]], x], {x, 0, \[DoubleStruckA]},
  PlotRange -> {0, 1.75},
  PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red}}]]
```

[image]

```
Show[
 Histogram[data, Automatic, "CDF"],
 Plot[Evaluate@CDF[dist[\[DoubleStruckA]], x], {x, 0, \[DoubleStruckA]},
  PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Very helpful.  Thanks.  ($\checkmark$).  I do think *Mathematica* should be able to handle the $a>0$ case, though.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Even in the simple case $a = 2$, note the support of $2X^2$ is on $(0,2)$.  For this reason, it is not a beta distribution but a location-scale transformation of one.  The closest thing I could find was the PERT distribution.  I am not aware of a specific named distribution for such a variable.  If you know of one, please do share it.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't.  And it doesn't work for $a = 1/2$ either.